# Simple regex to get a twitter username from a string

Tags: python, regex

Given a simple string like `"@dasweo where you at?"` i would like to write a regular expression to extract the `"dasweo"`.

What I have so far is:

```
print re.findall(r"@\w{*}", "@dasweo where you at?")
```

This does not work though. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want the `@` to be included in the match, you can use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=@)\w+", "@dasweo where you at?")
['dasweo']
```

In general, a regex of the form `(?<=X)Y` matches `Y` that is preceded by `X`, but does not include `X` in the actual match. In your case, `X` is `@` and `Y` is `\w+`, one or more word characters. A word character is either an alphanumeric character or an underscore.

By the way, there is more than one way to do this. You can also use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
>>> [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r"@(\w+)", "@dasweo where you at?")]
['dasweo']
```

`m.group(1)` returns the value of the first capturing group. In this case, that's whatever was matched by `\w+`.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `{..}` curly braces, they are not used with `*`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"@\w*", "@dasweo where you at?")
['@dasweo']
```

Only use `{..}` quantifiers with fixed numbers:

```
\w{3}
```

matches exactly 3 letters, for example.

Comment: Your answer has me a little confused.  Why didn't you do `re.findall(r"@(\w+)", "@dasweo where you at?")` so that it drops the "@" like the OP wanted as well as makes sure there is a name after the "@" (your current regex will capture just an "@" with no name)?

Comment: I missed that the OP wanted the name without the `@` and instead focused on the misunderstanding the OP had over the `{}` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern:

```
print re.findall(r"@\w+", "@dasweo where you at?")
```

The `\w` means any word character, while the `+` means one or more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
print re.findall(r"(?<=@)\w+", "@dasweo where you at?")
```

Where `(?<=..)` is a lookbehind that means: "preceded by" that performs only a check but doesn't capture.